# Flutter Error: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle

> Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
> Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
> Error.throwWithStackTrace(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
> Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
> ^
> ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firestore.dart:112:15: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
> Error.throwWithStackTrace(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
> Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
> Error.throwWithStackTrace(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
> Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
> ^

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/omair/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1070

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>   Process 'command '/Users/omair/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 13s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1'''

Any idea what's wrong here? Tried using different versions of firebase_auth but no resolution.

Current versions are:

firebase_core: ^1.12.0
firebase_analytics: ^9.1.0
firebase_auth: ^3.3.7
firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.0.6
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.9
fluttertoast: ^8.0.9

Thanks :)

Comment: Upgrading to the latest stable version of Flutter resolved the issue for me.

Comment: @NBM, which is 2.8.0 or which version ?

Comment: @Robin, its 2.10.3 released on 3rd March, 2022. Follow the link for further releases.
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases

Comment: @Robin, it is  2.10.3